# Equivalent of java window.pack() in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am very new to css. I am trying to create a border around a `<div>` and I want it to be limited to the size of the elements inside the `div` and dynamically sized in proportion to new objects to the objects that may be shown or hidden in the div.

I have tried messing with `border-radius:` and the `em` measurement but I am not making much progress. I have looked [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp) and  [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp) but neither really leads to something the equivalent of window.pack() in java. I am using css, javascript, and jquery. I don't think that it matters but the html is written mostly through ejs.

This is what I currently have but its just a box the width of the page:

```
{
border-style: solid;
border-color: blue;
border-radius: 1-4 length|% / 1-4 length|%;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "text frame"?

Comment: @blesh good call. edited for clarity

Comment: So you want your div to grow or shrink with the elements inside of it?

Comment: @blesh I want the border to grow or shrink with the elements inside of it. Is that the same thing?

Comment: The size of the box should grow and shrink? Or how thick the border line itself is should grow and shrink?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I *think* I know what you're asking.

The problem you might be seeing is that divs are, by default, `display:block`, which will cause them to stretch across their container (unless certain conditions are met, like explicit sizing, absolute positioning, etc).

Quick fix: In order to have them grow or shrink with content, you're going to have to set them to `display:inline-block`;

You also probably should study up on the CSS box model. [Here's a decent article to help with that](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/)

The border lives on the "outside" of the div. The div (if set to display: inline-block) will default to automatic width (aka, `width: auto`) and height (`height: auto`), which will cause it to grow or shrink with it's children. Since the border lives on the outside of the div, and the div is growing and shrinking, there you go.

Slightly more advanced, to add padding between the div content and the border, just set padding in CSS: `padding: 3px` for example. padding also "lives outside" of the div, but before the border. If that makes sense.

Edit: Also, if you're not familiar with the tool: [You might try playing with your HTML and CSS in something like JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G7z87/).

Comment: Thanks this is pretty much exactly what I am looking for